# Have RSpec verify that a method receives a particular block

Tags: ruby, rspec

How to I use `RSpec` to verify that a method receives a particular block?  Consider this simplified example:

```
class MyTest
  def self.apply_all_blocks(collection, target)
    collection.blocks.each do |block|
      target.use_block(&block)
    end
  end
end
```

I want a spec that verifies that `target.use_block` is called with each block returned by `collection.blocks`.

The following code does not work:

```
describe "MyTest" do
  describe ".apply_all_blocks" do
    it "applies each block in the collection" do
      target = double(Object)
      target.stub(:use_block)

      collection = double(Object)
      collection.stub(:blocks).and_return([:a, :b, :c])

      target.should_receive(:use_block).with(:a)
      target.should_receive(:use_block).with(:b)
      target.should_receive(:use_block).with(:c)

      MyTest.apply_all_blocks(collection, target)
    end
  end
end
```

(Also, `use_block` does not necessarily invoke the block, so it not sufficient to test that the block receives `call`.  Similarly, I don't think `target.should_receive(:use_block).and_yield` will do what I want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but the currently accepted answer is incorrect.

The correct way to verify a particular block is received is by passing a verification block to `should_receive` that specifically compares the received block to the block you expected to receive:

In RSpec 2.13 (current at the time of the original question):

```
a = lambda {}
target.should_receive(:use_block) do |&block|
  expect(block).to eq(a)
end
```

In RSpec 3.4 (current at time of writing this):

```
a = lambda {}
expect(target).to receive(:use_block) do |&block|
  expect(block).to eq(a)
end
```

Passing a block to `with` as was suggested in another answer is not adequate to verify that the block is actually received, because rspec uses that block to setup a return value, not to compare against the block the method actually receives.

See [documentation on passing blocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation) to `receive`.

Also see [recent discussion on RSpec mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/rspec/3bfa0a8a-4f55-4e24-8527-3f2f4eb693ea%40googlegroups.com).

Answer (score 3):

If you create lambdas instead of symbols, it will work as you expect:

```
describe "MyTest" do
  describe ".apply_all_blocks" do
    let(:a) { lambda {} }
    let(:b) { lambda {} }
    let(:c) { lambda {} }
    it "applies each block in the collection" do
      target = double(Object)
      target.stub(:use_block)

      collection = double(Object)
      collection.stub(:blocks).and_return([a, b, c])

      target.should_receive(:use_block).with(&a)
      target.should_receive(:use_block).with(&b)
      target.should_receive(:use_block).with(&c)

      MyTest.apply_all_blocks(collection, target)
    end
  end
end
```

*Note:* I changed the class name from `Test` to `MyTest` so it'll actually run; `Test` is going to clash with the real `Test` class.  I modified your question too, so that it's cut-and-paste runnable.

Comment: Although this spec passes, it is _not_ testing what you think it is.  When you pass a block to `with`, you're just specifying a return value. Rather than verifying that `use_block` is called with `a`, `b`, and `c`, this test merely verifies that `use_block` is called 3 times. You can prove this to yourself by changing `target.use_block(&block)` in the original method under test to be `target.use_block { 'some completely arbitrary block' }` and the spec will still pass.